# Compress Video While Preserving Alpha Channel

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, alpha, channel

I have a video with a transparent background that is very large despite being only 6 seconds. I was hoping I could compress it with FFmpeg but everything I try seems to discard the alpha channel...

This code brings the file down from 33gb to 24mb:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\djcim\Desktop\Intro For Now\Video Intro.avi" -map 0 -c:v libx264 -preset slow ^
-crf 17 -acodec copy "C:\Users\djcim\Desktop\Intro For Now\Compressed.avi"
```

But as stated I lose the alpha channel, any ideas on how I could significantly compress my file while preserving the alpha channel?

Comment: What's the input video codec, resolution, framerate?

Comment: Hello Gyan, when I probe the file with FFprobe it says codec_name=rawvideo, resolution is 3840x2160, framerate is 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various codecs that support alpha viz. qtrle, png, ffv1..etc

Try those 3 to check which yields the best size. All are lossless. The first two only support RGB pixels, whereas FFV1 supports both RGB and YUV but few applications support it. PNG is the most widely compatible.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i "Video Intro.avi" -map 0 -c:v png -c:a copy "Compressed.avi"
```

(Suggest using MOV container)

Comment: Used your above command and changed the output file to .mov, in one instance it brought a 33gb file down to 200mb, great! Only reduced another one from 44gb to 15gb, but I assume it's just because that one had more detail. Nonetheless much better, thank you!

Comment: Another approach is to use -c:v qtrle and then compress the resulting .mov file with 7z, it takes longer but can compress even more than png in most cases.

Comment: But then you need to unpack every time before playing/editing it.